# GCGamepad Deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ipad, gamepad

While testing one of our old iPad game (written in Objective-C), we found that GCGamepad is now deprecated. What is the replacement right now?

The game can still run perfectly on iOS 13 including gamepad support, but we would like to "modernise" it.

It surprise us that we can simply convert this game to Mac via Mac Catalyst! Everything works (including keyboard commands) except for gamepad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're meant to use GCExtendedGamepad now. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gcextendedgamepad?language=objc

Comment: Will it break any existing gamepads that we supported in the past?